# Integrate composite of non-linear function neural network

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, neural-networks

I need help integrating the following output of a 1 hidden layer auto-encoder neural network, a.k.a. integrating the reconstruction function. The encoder uses a relu function and so does the decoder.

Any ideas on how to do this?

$$\int relu\left ( W^T relu \left (Wx+b \right )+b' ) \right ) dx$$
where $W^T, W$ are matrices, $x, b,b'$ are vectors, and $relu(a) = \max(0,a)$.

Comment: what are you integrating over -- the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$? Also is $b' = b^T$ or just some other vector with no relationship to $b$?

Comment: the integral is indefinite. And $b' \neq b^T$. $b'$ it is just another vector with no relationship to b, but they are both of the same shape